# Creating and Displaying Deck of Cards with enums, C++

Tags: c++, enums

I've been able to do things along t he lines of decks and card before, but never with enums, and since I'm so new to the concept, I'm thrown through a loop. I want my program to do whatever the functions are titled, but I need to know if my current code would even create a deck, or how to display it. Enums are very strange to me, while I do my research on them, I hope my example code draws some help or suggestions. Thanks.

```
    #include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

enum suits { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES };
enum cardValues { TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE };

struct cards
{
    suits suit;
    cardValues card;
};

cards deck[52];
cards card1, card2;



void createDeck(cards[]);
void printDeck(cards[]);
void printCard(cards);
void deal(cards[], cards&);
void winner(cards, cards);


int main(){



}

void printDeck(cards[], cards deck[52]) {
    unsigned int count(1);

    for (unsigned int i(0); i < deck[52]; ++i)
    {
        cout << deck[i] << " ";
        if (count == 13)
        {
            cout << endl;
            count = 0;
        }
        ++count;
    }
```

Comment: Your current code won't create a deck b/c you haven't defined the create deck function.